Resizing Subplots Within a Figure
I have two subplots displayed side-by-side in one figure window, as shown.

Now, the aspect ratio (width-to-height ratio) of each photo is fixed, as is the proportion of the two images in relation to one another. I'd like to make the photos larger while keeping the size of the figure window the same, but I'm running into an issue. Here's the relevant snippet of my code:
%% DISPLAY IMAGES IN ONE FIGURE
fig = figure;
colormap(flipud(gray));

% Calculate the normalized heights based on image size
heightS = size(maxS, 1) / (size(maxS, 1) + size(maxC, 1));
heightC = size(maxC, 1) / (size(maxS, 1) + size(maxC, 1));

% Calculate the bottom position for vertical centering
bottomS = (1 - heightS) / 2;
bottomC = (1 - heightC) / 2;

% Saggital View
subplot('Position', [0, bottomS, 0.5, heightS]);
imagesc(maxS);
title("Saggital View")
axis off;
axis image;

% Coronal View
subplot('Position', [0.5, bottomC, 0.5, heightC]); 
imagesc(maxC);
title("Coronal View")
axis off;
axis image;

set(fig, 'Position', [100, 100, 1000, 500]); % Set the position and size of the figure

As you can see, both subplots supposedly have a width of 0.5, meaning they each take up exactly half of the figure window. So why do the images look so small? I have no idea. I'm aware there's additional space around the image taken up by invisble tick marks, labels, ex. but that doesn't really explain why the images are so small. I can't just increase their widths, because that would cause their combined width to exceed the figure size and result in the deletion of one of the subplots entirely. I need a way to make these images bigger without changing their aspect ratios, changing the size of the figure window, or changing the normalization of their values so they scale correclty with regards to one another. Does anyone have any ideas?

What is heightS? Why not set the height to 1? Use axis equal after to ensure a 1:1 aspect ratio of the displayed data.

Also, you can set the axes positons after cresting them all with subplot, it is the subplot function that deletes axes if they overlap. You can also create axes with axes instead, which doesn’t check for overlaps.

tiledlayout is quite good, and has replaced subplot for me. In your code, replace the first call to subplot with tiledlayout(1, 2, 'TileSpacing', 'tight'); nexttile(); and the next call to subplot with just nexttile();.

@magnesium tiledlayout does confer the same functionality as "subplot", however it displays the images as different heights. both arrays displayed by imagesc have 140 rows. the images should be the same height.

@CrisLuengo i have to normalize the values if i want the images to appear as the same height (they should have the same height, because the arrays that represent them have the same number of rows). if i set the height of both to one, the images display as different heights. i don't understand it either, to be honest.

@Bell You can adjust the axes scaling (using YLim and XLim, or only one of them in conjunction with axis equal), it's easier than trying to figure out their size.

not perfect (or fully tested) but this works alright for me: fig = figure; maxS = rand(140, 150); maxC = rand(140, 100); maxD = max([size(maxS), size(maxC)]); pad = 0.1; temp = @(siz) [siz(2)/maxD*(1-2*pad)/2, siz(1)/maxD*(1-2*pad)]; sz = @(siz) [ ([0.5,1]-temp(siz))/2 , temp(siz)]; subplot('Position', sz(size(maxS))); imagesc(maxS); axis image; subplot('Position', sz(size(maxC)) + [0.5 0 0 0]); imagesc(maxC); axis image; set(fig, 'Position', [100, 100, 1000, 500]);

I would approach this by defining an amount of padding you want around each subplot, and then simply using that to calculate the position. For example,
pad = 0.02;
width = 0.5-(2*pad);
height = 1-(2*pad);
sz1 = [pad pad width height]; % for first subplot
sz2 = sz1 + [0.5 0 0 0];      % for second subplot

gives reasonable results.
